# C# Treeview keys fullpath

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

There is this treeview with nodes added like so:

```
tree.Nodes.Add("key", "DisplayText");
tree.Nodes["key"].Nodes.Add("key2", "DisplayText2);
```

I want to obtain the full path of the currently selected node, but I want the path of keys not the path of display text.

If the second node is selected, the tree.FullPath property will return the following:

```
"DisplayText\\DisplayText2"
```

But this is pointless to me, what I need is

```
"Key\\Key2"
```

What is the fastest way to acquire the full key path ?

Comment: You could use a recursive function that will return the `Name` property of each `TreeNode` in the `TreeView` for the currently selected `TreeNode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeNode.Name` will give you the key values. There is no such property/method to return the path containing the key values. `FullPath` will give you path with display values. You can recurse to build the path with key values with something like this:

```
public string GetKeyPath(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Parent == null)
    {
        return node.Name;
    }

    return GetKeyPath(node.Parent) + "//" + node.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pseudo-code rough idea.. not complete code, but just to give you an idea of where to start:

```
string ParentNodeName(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Parent == null)
    {
        return node.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        return ParentNodeName(node.Parent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I needed an array anyway I figured I could make a function that receives a Treenode and returns an array of string containing the keys.

```
    private string[] FullKeyPath(TreeNode tn)
    {
        string[] path = new string[tn.Level + 1];
        for (int i = tn.Level; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            path[i] = tn.Name.ToString();
            if (tn.Parent != null)
            {
                tn = tn.Parent;
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```